# debugging tornado server in docker container

Tags: python, eclipse, docker, tornado, pydev

I use [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/) with Eclipse as an IDE.

How can I debug a tornado server running inside a docker container using PyDev/Eclipse?

Is it possible to put breakpoints in PyDev/Eclipse and debug like a server running natively on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using the remote debugger, so, you can add connect the running program to the Eclipse remote debugger (see http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html). The only thing here is that it has to create a connection from the container to the host.

Another thing which **could** work (as in: I've never tested it) is creating an interpreter which always runs inside docker... an interpreter in PyDev can be any executable (such as a .sh), so, you can try making a script which will run python inside docker by default (although as I never tested this I can't say how well that'll work).